# Look up a dynamic property at run-time in Spring from PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer?

Tags: spring, properties

Not sure of the best approach to this. We've created a jar that could be used by different projects. The other projects relying on this jar need to provide certain properties defined in one of their spring properties files. (Our jar shouldn't care what they name those property files.)

Using @Value("${some.prop}") works great for most properties, however we now have the requirement that the name of the property to look up is dynamic. For example:

```
int val = getSomeVal();
String propNeeded = foo.getProperty("foo."+val+".dynamic.prop");
```

Not sure what "foo" should be to get my access. I looked into injecting Environment, however from all my googling it looks like that will not load from an xml property-placeholder definition (even if defined as a bean def for PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.) You seem to have to use @PropertySource, yet my main config is an XML file so not sure how to get Environment to work. (I can't really go 'old skool' and look up the property file as a class path Resource either since I'm not aware of the name of the file the users defined.)

I don't mind making this particular Service class ApplicationContextAware, but if I did that how could I get access to the underlying PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ? which I would 'seem?' to need in order to get access to a property dynamically?

The other option is that I force users of the jar to declare a bean by a name that I can look up

```
    <util:properties id="appProps" location="classpath:application.properties"  />
```

And I then inject appProps as Properties and look up from there. I don't like this approach though since it forces the users of the library to name an file by a common id. I would think the best solution is to just get a handle in some way to the underlying PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in my service class... I'm just not sure how to do it?

Why doesn't Spring simply allow PropertySource to be defined some how via your XML config and then I could just inject Environment?

Thanks for any suggestions how to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html) declared to read from the same source as the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. This way you could just @Autowire MessageSource (or make your bean implement MessageSourceAware) and use that to retrieve your properties.

Main reason for using ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource is to retrieve I18N messages, so that would kind of hacky...